# Pull down view (menu) from ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I need to implement a pull-down view that has a "handle" in right-most part of the ActionBar. It should be full width and open with an animation when the handle is clicked, and additionally the handle itself should be draggable. minSdkVersion is 8

Regarding the pull-down functionality itself, I found that [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) isn't going to fit the bill, since it has been deprecated as of API v17, and it can only be opened from bottom to top. The control [SlidingTray](http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/com/sileria/android/view/SlidingTray.html) seems to overcome that issue. I haven't tested it thoroughly but but it seems to work as expected.

Now to the main issue. Is it even possible to display the view in such a manner? I have tried to set a custom view for the ActionBar, where the inflated XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <my.package.drawer.SlidingTray
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </my.package.drawer.SlidingTray>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the SlidingTray view itself is functioning as expected when I put it in the activity/fragment layout (can drag the handle and click it to open/close the tray), but when inflating the layout above inside the ActionBar, and upon pressing/dragging the handle, the Tray only moves a few pixels before stopping - **it doesn't go beyond the ActionBar bounds**. This is the main issue - can the view go beyond the ActionBar itself (over the activity displayed below), and if so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered, I'll post how I resolved the issue.
After some inspecting with hierarchyviewer, I saw that the ActionBar was in a LinearLayout and as such, it wouldn't be possible to extend a child of it outside of the ActionBar bounds. So I decided to get the root (decor) view and attach the modified version of SlidingDrawer there. Here is the excerpt:

```
ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View drawerContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_drawer, null);
drawer = (SlidingDrawer) drawerContainer.findViewById(R.id.drawer);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
decor.addView(drawerContainer, params);
```

Since adding a view this way displays it behind the Status bar, I also added a container view with top padding of 25dp so that the handle and content are displayed beneath it.

Note: if you are using the [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library, you need to do this in `onPostCreate()`, because the library also does this and will place your view behind all of the other content.